# $\lambda P( \min_{1 \leq k \leq n}X_k\leq -\lambda) \leq \int_{\{\min_{1 \leq k \leq n}X_k> -\lambda\}}X_ndP - E[X_0]$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}^*.$ $(X_k)_k$ is a submartingale, $\lambda>0,$ ***by considering***, for $1 \leq k \leq n, E_k=\bigcap_{r=1}^{k-1}\{X_r >-\lambda\}\cap\{X_k \leq -\lambda\},$ prove that $$\lambda P( \min_{1 \leq k \leq n}X_k\leq -\lambda) \leq \int_{\{\min_{1 \leq k \leq n}X_k> -\lambda\}}X_ndP - E[X_0].$$

$\{\min_{1 \leq k \leq n}X_k \leq -\lambda\}=\bigcup_{k=1}^nE_k,$ also $E_k$ are disjoint so $P(\min_{1 \leq k \leq n}X_k\ \leq - \lambda)=\sum_{k=1}^nP(E_k)$ also $\int_{E_k}X_kdP \leq -\lambda P(E_k).$
Also $X_k \leq E[X_n |\mathcal{F}_k].$

Having a problem how to continue from here, especially how to use that $(X_k)_k$ is a submartingale ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\{ \min_{1 \leq k \leq n}X_k\leq -\lambda\}$, and
$$N=\inf\{m: X_m\leq-\lambda\text{ or }m=n\},$$
then $X_N\leq-\lambda$ on $A$ and $X_N=X_n$ on $A^c$. Hence $E[X_N1_A]\leq-\lambda P(A)$ and
$$E[X_n1_{A^c}]=E[X_N1_{A^c}]=E[X_N]-E[X_N1_A]\geq E[X_N]+\lambda P(A).$$

Since $N$ is a bounded stopping time with $P(N\leq n)=1$ and $X_n$ is a submartingale, we have
$$E[X_0]\leq E[X_N]\leq E[X_n].$$
Therefore
$$E[X_n1_{A^c}]\geq E[X_0]+\lambda P(A),$$
as desired.

Comment: We need to use $E_k$ (without using stopping times and their properties since they are not covered yet)

Comment: The usage of stopping itmes is a great difference between probability theory and stochastic processes, so I highly recommend you to learn it as earlier as you can. Here we didn't use the stopping time property unless $E[X_0]\leq E[X_N]$. You can use the property $\{N\leq k\}\in \mathcal{F}_{k-1}$ to show that $\{X_{N\wedge k}-X_0\}$ is a submartingale and then get $E[X_0]\leq E[X_N]$. This is a good exercise for you to understand the definition of submartingales.

Comment: @john  Sorry, I mean $\{N\leq k\}\in \mathcal{F}_k$ and so $\{N\geq k\}\in \mathcal{F}_{k-1}$.